# Chrome v60 rendering bug?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've come across an issue in the latest version of Chrome (Version 60.0.3112.78) when having a child element of an absolutely positioned parent element being positioned fixed (along with some other CSS attributes).

Here's a CodePen to demonstrate the behaviour: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvJeGL

```
    <div class="outer">
       <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>

.outer {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 100px);
    top: calc(50% - 100px);
    z-index: 1; /* auto fixes rendering */
    border-radius: 5px; /* 0 fixes rendering, other values give strange results */
    overflow: hidden; /* visible fixes rendering */
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.inner {
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    height: 75%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: salmon;
}
```

This issuse appeared when I updated Chrome to major version 60 (it works in 59). Safari also seem to have issues.

If you play with the CSS values in the Codepen of the ".outer" element you will notice that the rendering behaviour changes. Interesting that border-radius has an effect.

Is this a bug or can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm seeking to understand if this is a bug, or if it's not; an explanation to this very odd rendering behaviour.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I have also come across numerous errors recently, relating to the use of `overflow: hidden` in the updated version (V60) of Google Chrome.

Comment: Strangely, with your codepen, if I drag the Chrome window between my left and right monitors, I can see the rendering change. I'm on Mac Sierra with Chrome 60.